# Force return after render in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `rails 4.2.1`

I want to write a function that forces the controller it was called in to render and return.  Is this possible?

```
def error!
  # do stuff to define error
  # now render error
  render
end

def SomeController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  include ActionController::Renderers::All
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  def some_action
    if something
      # good - continue
    else
      # bad - error!
      error!
      # how to force controller to stop execution and return here?
      # return error! # I could do this
      # but could I do it in the error! function?
    end
    puts 'Still Running'
  end
end
```

Comment: what if you pass controller instance into `error!(controller)` as a parameter and do `controller.render` ?

Answer (score 1):

check

```
def some_action
   if something
     # good - continue
   else         
     return error!         
   end
  puts 'Still Running'
end
```

Another option is to raise an exception within `error!`, and have some rescue_from block at `ApplicationController` level